# wifidirect connection for filesharing

Tags: android, wifi-direct

**1. i create a application for android file sharing,but i have one error for my coding,the search peer function is not working correctly anybody can help me please.?The following on the my code. 
      package com.example.com.MARK2;

```
import java.io.BufferedReader; import java.io.BufferedWriter; import
java.io.File; import java.io.FileReader; import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException; import java.util.HashMap; import
java.util.Iterator; import java.util.Set;

import android.app.Activity; import android.app.AlertDialog; import
android.content.BroadcastReceiver; import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface; import
android.content.Intent; import android.content.IntentFilter; import
android.net.wifi.p2p.WifiP2pConfig; import
android.net.wifi.p2p.WifiP2pDevice; import
android.net.wifi.p2p.WifiP2pManager; import
android.net.wifi.p2p.WifiP2pManager.ActionListener; import
android.net.wifi.p2p.WifiP2pManager.Channel; import
android.net.wifi.p2p.WifiP2pManager.ChannelListener; import
android.os.Bundle; import android.provider.Settings; import
android.util.Log; import android.view.Menu; import
android.view.MenuInflater; import android.view.MenuItem; import
android.view.View; import android.widget.TextView; import
android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements
ChannelListener{

    private WifiP2pManager manager;
    private Channel channel;
    private BroadcastReceiver receiver;
    private final IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter();
    private boolean isWifiP2pEnabled = false;
    Context CONTEXT=this;
    private boolean retryChannel=false;
    public final static int BYTESPERCHUNK=100000;
    static HashMap<String, String> allFileList= new HashMap<String, String>();
    static HashMap<String, Integer> numOfChunks= new HashMap<String, Integer>();
    static String fileNeeded=new String();

     @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        File file= new File("/sdcard/raja");
        if(!file.exists()) file.mkdirs();
        initialization();
       fileNeeded=getFileNeeded();
        intentFilter.addAction(WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION);
        intentFilter.addAction(WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_PEERS_CHANGED_ACTION);
        intentFilter.addAction(WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_CONNECTION_CHANGED_ACTION);
        intentFilter.addAction(WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_THIS_DEVICE_CHANGED_ACTION);

        manager = (WifiP2pManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_P2P_SERVICE);
        channel = manager.initialize(this, getMainLooper(), null);
        receiver = new WiFiDirectBroadcastReceiver(manager, channel, this);
        registerReceiver(receiver, intentFilter);
        //searchPeer();
    }
    @Override
    public void onResume() { 
        super.onResume();
        registerReceiver(receiver, intentFilter);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() { 
        super.onPause();
        unregisterReceiver(receiver);
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menuitem, menu);
        return true;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.exit:             
            disconnect();
            cancelDisconnect();
            unregisterReceiver(receiver);
            this.finish();
            System.exit(0);
            return true;
            case R.id.folder:           
            Intent browseFolder= new Intent(this,BrowserFolder.class);
            startActivity(browseFolder);    
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }
    public void setIsWifiP2pEnabled(boolean isWifiP2pEnabled) {
        this.isWifiP2pEnabled = isWifiP2pEnabled;
        return;
    }

    public void showMessage(String str){    Toast.makeText(CONTEXT, str,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    public void searchButton(View view){    searchPeer();   return;
    }


    public void searchPeer(){
            if(!isWifiP2pEnabled){
            new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
            .setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
            .setTitle("WiFi Direct is Disabled!")
            .setPositiveButton("Setting", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                    startActivity(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_WIRELESS_SETTINGS)); 
                }
            }).show();
            return;
        }
      /*  if(fileNeeded==null){
        showMessage("You have ALL files updated. Don't need to transfer anymore.");
        return;
        }*/     final DeviceListFragment fragment = (DeviceListFragment) getFragmentManager()
                    .findFragmentById(R.id.devicelist);     fragment.onInitiateDiscovery();
    fragment.getView().setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    manager.discoverPeers(channel, new WifiP2pManager.ActionListener()
{
             @Override
             public void onSuccess() {
                 //Toast.makeText(CONTEXT, "Searching",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                 return;
             }
             @Override
             public void onFailure(int reasonCode) {
                 Toast.makeText(CONTEXT, "Search Failed: "+reasonCode,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                 return;
             }
         });
    }

    public static String getDeviceStatus(int deviceStatus) {
        switch (deviceStatus) {
            case WifiP2pDevice.AVAILABLE:
                return "Available";
            case WifiP2pDevice.INVITED:
                return "Invited";
            case WifiP2pDevice.CONNECTED:
                return "Connected";
            case WifiP2pDevice.FAILED:
                return "Failed";
            case WifiP2pDevice.UNAVAILABLE:
                return "Unavailable";
            default:
                return "Unknown";

        }
    }

    public static int divRoundUp(int n,int s){  return (((n) / (s)) + ((((n) % (s)) > 0) ? 1 : 0));
    }

    public void updateThisDevice(WifiP2pDevice device) {
        TextView view = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.mystatus);
        view.setText("My Name: "+device.deviceName+"\nMy Address: "+device.deviceAddress+"\nMy Status:
"+getDeviceStatus(device.status));
        return;
    }

    public void connect(WifiP2pConfig config){   manager.connect(channel, config, new ActionListener() {
         @Override
         public void onSuccess() {

         }

         @Override
         public void onFailure(int reason) {         showMessage("Connect failed: "+reason);
         }   });                 return;
    }


    public void disconnect(){
        final DeviceDetailFragment fragment = (DeviceDetailFragment) getFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.devicedetail);
        fragment.blockDetail();
        updateRecord();
        manager.removeGroup(channel, new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(int reasonCode) {
                showMessage("Disconnect failed. Reason :" + reasonCode);
            }

            @Override
            public void onSuccess() {
                //fragment.getView().setVisibility(View.GONE); 
            showMessage("Disconnected.");
            }
        });
        return;
    }


    @Override
    public void onChannelDisconnected() {
        if (manager != null && !retryChannel) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Channel lost. Trying again", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            retryChannel = true;
            manager.initialize(this, getMainLooper(), this);
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this,
                    "Channel is probably lost premanently. Try Disable/Re-Enable P2P.",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        return; 
    }


    public void cancelDisconnect() {
        if (manager != null) {
            final DeviceDetailFragment fragment = (DeviceDetailFragment) getFragmentManager()
                    .findFragmentById(R.id.devicedetail);
            if (fragment.device == null
                    || fragment.device.status == WifiP2pDevice.CONNECTED) {
                disconnect();
            } else if (fragment.device.status == WifiP2pDevice.AVAILABLE
                    || fragment.device.status == WifiP2pDevice.INVITED) {

                manager.cancelConnect(channel, new ActionListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess() {
                        showMessage("Aborting connection");
                        return;
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(int reasonCode) {
                        showMessage("Connect abort request failed. Reason Code: " + reasonCode);
                    }
                });
            }
        }
        return;
    }

     /* 
    static HashMap<String, HashMap<String, Boolean>> availableFileChunks= new HashMap<String, HashMap<String,
Boolean>>();
    static HashMap<String, HashMap<String, Boolean>> neededFileChunks= new HashMap<String, HashMap<String, Boolean>>();
    void initialization(){  File listFile=new File("/sdcard/akalyvan.txt");     File recordFile=new
File("/sdcard/akalyvan2.txt");  try {
        BufferedReader inputReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(listFile));
        String buffer = new String(); 
        while((buffer=inputReader.readLine())!=null){           String [] fileInfo= buffer.split(",");              allFileList.put(fileInfo[0],
fileInfo[1]);       int
num=divRoundUp(Integer.parseInt(fileInfo[2]),BYTESPERCHUNK);
        numOfChunks.put(fileInfo[0],num);
        }
        inputReader.close();
        inputReader=new BufferedReader(new FileReader(recordFile));
        while((buffer=inputReader.readLine())!=null){           String [] fileInfo= buffer.split(",");      
        if((buffer=inputReader.readLine())!=null){
            HashMap<String, Boolean> chunkMap= new HashMap<String, Boolean>();
            String [] chunkNum= buffer.split(",");
            for(int i=0;i<chunkNum.length;i++){             chunkMap.put(chunkNum[i], true);
            }
            availableFileChunks.put(fileInfo[0], chunkMap);         }
        }
        inputReader.close();
        Set<String>files= allFileList.keySet();
        Iterator<String> it=files.iterator();
        while(it.hasNext()){        buffer=it.next();       if(availableFileChunks.get(buffer)==null){
            HashMap<String, Boolean> chunkMap= new HashMap<String, Boolean>();
            for(int i=0;i<numOfChunks.get(buffer);i++){             chunkMap.put(new Integer(i).toString(), true);
            }
            neededFileChunks.put(buffer, chunkMap);         }else{
            HashMap<String, Boolean> chunkMap=availableFileChunks.get(buffer);
            HashMap<String, Boolean> neededChunkMap= new HashMap<String, Boolean>();
            for(int i=0;i<numOfChunks.get(buffer);i++){             if(chunkMap.get(new Integer(i).toString())==null){
                neededChunkMap.put(new Integer(i).toString(), true);            }
            } 
            neededFileChunks.put(buffer, neededChunkMap);       }
        }   } catch (IOException e) {
        showMessage("IO Error.");   }

    }
    public static String getFileNeeded(){   String result=new String();     Set<String> files=neededFileChunks.keySet();
    if(files.isEmpty()) return null;    Iterator<String>
it=files.iterator();    int i=0;    while(it.hasNext()){
        if(i++!=0) result+=",";
        String buffer=it.next();
        result+=buffer+",";
        HashMap<String, Boolean> neededChunkMap=neededFileChunks.get(buffer);
        Set<String> chunks=neededChunkMap.keySet();
        Iterator<String> chunkit=chunks.iterator();
        int j=0;
        while(chunkit.hasNext()){       if(j++!=0) result+="+";         result+=chunkit.next();
        }   }   return result;  
    }

    public void updateRecord(){     File recordFile=new File("/sdcard/akalyvan2.txt");  try {
        BufferedWriter outputWriter = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(recordFile,false));
        Set<String>files= availableFileChunks.keySet();
        Iterator<String> it=files.iterator();
        while(it.hasNext()){        outputWriter.write(it.next()+"\n");         HashMap<String, Boolean>
chunkMap=availableFileChunks.get(it.next());        Set<String> chunks=
chunkMap.keySet();      Iterator<String> chunkit=chunks.iterator();
        String chunkList=new String();      int i=0;
        while(chunkit.hasNext()){
            if(i++!=0) chunkList+=",";
            chunkList+=chunkit.next();      }       outputWriter.write(chunkList+"\n");
        }
        outputWriter.flush();
        outputWriter.close();   } catch (IOException e) {
        showMessage("IO Error.");   }
    }*/

    public static HashMap<String, BitMap> availableChunkMap= new HashMap<String, BitMap>();
    public static HashMap<String, BitMap> neededChunkMap= new HashMap<String, BitMap>();
    void initialization(){  File listFile=new File("/sdcard/akalyvan3.txt");    File recordFile=new
File("/sdcard/gurubitmaprecord.txt");   try {
        if(!listFile.exists()){         showMessage("Fatal Error: Config file not found.");         return;
        }
        BufferedReader inputReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(listFile));
        String buffer = new String(); 
        while((buffer=inputReader.readLine())!=null){           String [] fileInfo= buffer.split(",");              allFileList.put(fileInfo[0],
fileInfo[1]);       int
num=divRoundUp(Integer.parseInt(fileInfo[2]),BYTESPERCHUNK);
        numOfChunks.put(fileInfo[0],num);
        File oneFile= new File("/sdcard/raja/"+fileInfo[1]);        if(oneFile.exists()){
            BitMap chunkMap= new BitMap(num);
            for(int i=0;i<num;i++) chunkMap.Mark(i);
            availableChunkMap.put(fileInfo[0], chunkMap);                       }
        }
        inputReader.close();
        recordFile.createNewFile();
        inputReader=new BufferedReader(new FileReader(recordFile));
        while((buffer=inputReader.readLine())!=null){           String [] fileInfo= buffer.split(",");  
        if(availableChunkMap.get(fileInfo[0])!=null){
        buffer=inputReader.readLine();
            continue;       }       if((buffer=inputReader.readLine())!=null){  
            BitMap chunkMap= new BitMap(buffer);
            if(chunkMap.length()!=numOfChunks.get(fileInfo[0])){            showMessage("Error: BitMap length not correct");            return;
            }
            availableChunkMap.put(fileInfo[0], chunkMap);       }
        }
        inputReader.close();
         Set<String>files= allFileList.keySet();
        Iterator<String> it=files.iterator();
        while(it.hasNext()){        buffer=it.next();       if(availableChunkMap.get(buffer)==null){
            BitMap chunkMap=new BitMap(numOfChunks.get(buffer));
            for(int i=0;i<numOfChunks.get(buffer);i++){             chunkMap.Mark(i);
            }
            neededChunkMap.put(buffer, chunkMap);       }else{
            BitMap chunkMap=availableChunkMap.get(buffer);
            if(chunkMap.numMarked()==numOfChunks.get(buffer)) continue;
            BitMap neededChunk= new BitMap(numOfChunks.get(buffer));
            for(int i=0;i<numOfChunks.get(buffer);i++){             if(!chunkMap.Test(i)){
                neededChunk.Mark(i);            }
            } 
            neededChunkMap.put(buffer, neededChunk);        }
        }   } catch (IOException e) {
        showMessage("IO Error: "+e.toString());     }   
    }

    public static String getFileNeeded(){   String result=new String();     Set<String> files=neededChunkMap.keySet();
    //if(files.isEmpty()) return null;  Iterator<String>
it=files.iterator();    int i=0;    while(it.hasNext()){
        if(i++!=0) result+=",";
        String buffer=it.next();
        result+=buffer+",";
            result+=neededChunkMap.get(buffer).toString();  }   return result;  
    }

    public static void updateRecord(){  File recordFile=new File("/sdcard/gurubitmaprecord.txt");   try {
        BufferedWriter outputWriter = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(recordFile,false));
        Set<String>files= availableChunkMap.keySet();
        Iterator<String> it=files.iterator();
        while(it.hasNext()){        String buffer=it.next();        outputWriter.write(buffer+","+allFileList.get(buffer)+"\n");
        BitMap chunkMap=availableChunkMap.get(buffer);
        outputWriter.write(chunkMap.toString()+"\n");
        }
        outputWriter.flush();
        outputWriter.close();   } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.d("EE579","IO Error.");     }
    }
        /*    public static BloomFilter availableChunks=new BloomFilter();
    void initialization(){  File listFile=new File("/sdcard/akalyvan2t.txt");   try {
        if(!listFile.exists()){         showMessage("Fatal Error: Config file not found.");         return;
        }
        BufferedReader inputReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(listFile));
        String buffer = new String(); 
        while((buffer=inputReader.readLine())!=null){           String [] fileInfo= buffer.split(",");              allFileList.put(fileInfo[0],
fileInfo[1]);       int
num=divRoundUp(Integer.parseInt(fileInfo[2]),BYTESPERCHUNK);
        numOfChunks.put(fileInfo[0],num);       File oneFile= new
File("/sdcard/raja/"+fileInfo[1]);      if(oneFile.exists()){
            for(int i=0;i<num;i++){             availableChunks.mark(fileInfo[0]+"-"+i);
            }       }
        }
        inputReader.close();
        File oneFile= new File("/sdcard/raja/tmp");
        if(oneFile.exists()){       File[] files=oneFile.listFiles();       for(int i=0;i<files.length;i++){
            String fileName= files[i].getName().split("\\.")[0];
            availableChunks.mark(fileName);         }
        }   }catch(IOException e){
        showMessage("IO Error: "+e.toString());     }
    }
    public static String getFileNeeded(){   String result=new String();     Set<String>files= allFileList.keySet();     Iterator<String>
it=files.iterator();    while(it.hasNext()){
        String buffer=it.next();
        for(int i=0;i<numOfChunks.get(buffer);i++){         if(!availableChunks.test(buffer+"-"+i)){
            result+=buffer+"-"+i+",";       }
        }   }   return result;  
    }*/ }**
```

Comment: post ur receiver class

Comment: And please, format your code so it'll be possible to read it (e.g. remove comments, imports).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is not readable. So I couldn't find bug in this class. May be you are doing something wrong in Broadcast receiver class from where peers got update.
You can follow this link for better understanding of code. Sample app is there, review that code and find bug in your code.

[How can I transfer files between Android devices using Wi-Fi Direct?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25638335/how-to-transfer-files-between-android-devices-using-wifi-direct/31531931#31531931)

I hope it will help you.